# Unable to connect my bluetooth with my wireless earphones

Tags: bluetooth

```
aditya@aditya-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-03-01 06:04:13 EST; 15min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 4456 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─4456 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mar 01 06:04:13 aditya-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service.
Mar 01 06:04:13 aditya-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth service.
Mar 01 06:04:13 aditya-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service.
Mar 01 06:04:13 aditya-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 01 06:04:13 aditya-HP-15-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[4456]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
Mar 01 06:04:13 aditya-HP-15-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[4456]: Starting SDP server
Mar 01 06:04:13 aditya-HP-15-Notebook-PC bluetoothd[4456]: Bluetooth management
```

my bluetooth is active but then  I found no bluetooth in rfkill list >>

```
aditya@aditya-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
aditya@aditya-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ ^C



aditya@aditya-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

why no default controllr availble

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.